# When I use helpgrep, how can I highlight my search results?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, gvim, vim-windows, highlighting

I'm using `:helpg session` in my Vim.

I would like to highlight the pattern in the results like `:set hls` does for normal search.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl for example I want to use                
 `:helpgrep word1.*word4
:helpgrep word1\|word4` and I need to highlight these words.

Comment: That's what you want to do. I'm asking what you tried to do to achieve that.

Comment: @romainl I have no idea ):

Comment: Whenever you jump to one of the matches, your cursor is exactly on the word. It should be visible. To highlight additional matches, you could just press `*` to go to the next match (thereby triggering highlight).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `match` command:

```
" Open the quickfix buffer
:cw
" Use 'Search' highlighting group to highlight your pattern
:match Search /word1.*word4/
```

If you frequently perform these actions, you could create a custom command to combine them.